# How do I configure the Raspberry Pi Zero with appropriate parameters to run the TI DLP2000EVM DMD?

Tags: i2c

I've followed the best tutorials online but to no avail.

In particular, one thread on TI, to which I cannot post or ask questions, and one written for the raspberry pi 3B+ which references the original post.

https://e2e.ti.com/support/dlp-products-group/dlp/f/dlp-products-forum/651931/linux-dlpdlcr2000evm-integration-of-raspberry-pi-video

http://frederickvandenbosch.be/?p=2948

I have modified my config.txt file as per both, but the pinouts from the two tutorials appear to be quite different. I used the TI forum pinout.

Behavior at boot :

Both boards have AC/DC plugs.

No shared power between boards.

But some GNDs? Are shared? I think? Check the TI pinout. I followed that.

At boot, rpi has a USB hub and mouse and keyboard.

At first I start without an HDMI.

The EVM shows its power on splash screen and though the raspberry pi green light flickers alot, it never appears to use DPI on the i2c bus.

The second website, Vandenbosch guy, says to add two lines to the etc/rc.local ( I think that's the file?). These should automatically switch the EVM splash to the r Pi screen. These lines assert / switch the video over the i2c bus; to the r pi video output.

I've done that. But the rpi never passes its splash screen to the DLP2000EVM.

Now. If I hard shutdown and start up again, but with an HDMI hookup to the to the pi zero, it hangs on the rainbow splash screen.

No chance to login. No shot at command line for an i2cdetect command / query.

If I hard shutdown, yank the micro SD card and plug into my other Linux computer and remove all the config.txt and rc.local amendments, and then boot up the r pi, HDMI connected, it boots me into desktop no problem.

Bur then, of course, no i2c or DPI connection to DLP2000EVM.

But at least I know I've broken nothing.

I have to assume that since my modified card will still boot to HDMI ( though it subsequently hangs?) that there must be some switch I'm supposed to blacklist to shut HDMI capability off? Some line to comment out in config.txt? Some overlay to remove? Or device tree overlay to remove? Perhaps from the command.txt. file?

Please help. I'm downright annoyed by the poor documentation abd poor explanations i've read so far.

Comment: This post is full of TLAs but no data.

Comment: Wiring diagrams, photos of connections, proof that I2C is working?

Comment: OK? TI = texas instruments. AC = alternating current. DC = Direct current. USB = Universal Serial Bus . GND = Ground. HDMI = I dunno, something that plugs into a TV monitro ... High Density / Definition M's and I's? EVM is part number/name from TI, for the "Evaluation Module". DLP = Digital Light Projector. It is also a DMD = Digital Micromirror Device. I can take a picture of what I have so far. and maybe get a screenshot of error messages and whatnot? Maybe next time. In a month or so. i am pretty busy with other projects. DPI ? = Display? Peripheral? interface? Maybe? SD card is an SD card?